# what is field name for image sort order in CSV to import product from dataflow profile?

Tags: import, image, dataflow

I want to upload import bulk images in magento.

Each product has three images, so sort order of image is must while importing in bulk.

But after a lot googling i didn't find field name for image sort order.

(In case of API its equivalent is "position")

Anyone please tell me What is field name for image sort order in CSV imported from dataflow profile?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I concern it is not possible with neither generic Magento import, nor with Magmi. Some commercial import script might do it though.

To me the closest bet would be customizing Magmi image plugin which is quite easy.

Comment: Its really shocking!
I wonder how to manage images sort order while importing bulk products?
Is there any trick?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried 'position column' from 'catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value' table?

A sample SQL query to achieve this would be -

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_media_gallery AS mg,
    catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value AS mgv,
    catalog_product_entity_varchar AS ev
SET ev.value = mg.value
WHERE  mg.value_id = mgv.value_id
AND mg.entity_id = ev.entity_id
AND ev.attribute_id IN (70, 71, 72)
AND mgv.position = 1;
```

Backup your database before playing with this. Getting the previous state back is not so easy.